# ubuntu 13.04 brightness problem on laptop

Tags: ati, laptop, 13.04, brightness

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 and the proprietary AMD catalyst  driver 13.4.

After installing the driver, the brightness of the screen has turned to the lowest and can not be changed. No matter how I scrolled the brightness bar, the brightness doesn't change.

I tried editing grub with `acpi_backlight=vendor`. But, it didn't work and the brightness hotkeys stopped working.

Note that Ubuntu 12.04 works perfectly without a single issue. What can I do to solve the problem in Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: Please add the model of your laptop to the question!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but have solved this by doing the following steps:

- First, check your brightness operator by using the following command:

  `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` this will output like:
  `/sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight/brightness
  /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`(in my case).
- Next, check your current brightness by using the following command:

  `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

  (replace intel_backlight to your backlight operator that was output in above command).this will output like`455`.
- Now, check for maximum brightness:

  `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`
  this will output like `4882`
- Now, your brightness could be from 0 to 4882 and  you can adjust it by using the following command:

  `echo 450 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`.
  (I have done it for saving my brightness 450).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue on a Dell Pavilion dv7 when upgrading from a Wonderful installation of 12.10 to 13.04 (so far "upgrade" is not really the description I'd use...)

Anyway, I had to edit /etc/rc.local and add:

```
echo 8 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

before the `exit 0`, then `sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local` to make sure it gets run.